# How do I do a right join and return only null values in EntityFramework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have two tables, NAttrValues and NAttrTitles. The NAttrTitles have an ID, which is referenced in the NAttrValues table by the column 'TitleID'. I'm trying to return the elements in NAttrTitles that do not have any associated NAttrValues, using LINQ in EntityFramework.

This SQL query returns exactly what I want

```
SELECT * FROM NAttrValues nav RIGHT JOIN NAttrTitles nat ON nav.TitleID = nat.ID WHERE nav.TitleID IS NULL
```

How do I write this in EntityFramework? I've tried various different uses of .DefaultIfEmpty() but they all end up returning either the wrong thing, or nothing at all.

Comment: A search for "linq right join" turns up several questions with answers here on SO. Perhaps one of those can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right Outer Join is the same as [Left Outer Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx#Anchor_2) with left and right sides swapped. So the LINQ To Entities equivalent of your SQL query is:

```
var query =
    from nat in db.NAttrTitles
    join nav in db.NAttrValues on nat.ID equals nav.TitleID into nat_nav
    from nav in nat_nav.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where nav == null
    select nat;
```

Comment: That's the one! That's what I was trying to arrive at. Can you explain why I need to store the join into nat_nav and then do the DefaultIfEmpty() on that? That's something I've never understood.

Comment: Because there is no natural LINQ operator for left outer join. As you can see from the link, the pattern for left outer join is always one and the same `from a in A join b in B on a.Key equals b.Key into a_b from b in a_b.DefaultIfEmpty()`. There is no need to be understood it, just know that this is the pattern and it is recognized by the query providers.